# Run Watch OS 1 simulator in xcode7

Tags: xcode, simulator, watch

I'm not able to run watch OS1 simulator on the new xcode 7.

I want to test our new watch OS2 app (to see what happens, or if we can show a alert info to the user) when it's trying to run an app for watch OS2 on watch OS1.

it's possible?

thanks